# WPF Bind to itself

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, self

I've got a WPF `Window`, and somewhere there is a `ListView` where I bind a `List<string>` to.

Now somewhere in my `ListView` there is a `TextBox` and the `Content` property is set to `{Binding}`.

But this is the shorthand.  How do I write the full binding to bind to itself?

`{Binding Path=Self}` doesn't work, neither does `{Binding Self}` (where the latter is a shortcut for the former).

Comment: I want to mention to a post related to this topic.The above answer is totally correct but there is a point that completes the above answer. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995318/how-do-i-bind-to-relativesource-self).

Answer (score 278, accepted):

**Short answer**:`{Binding}` is *not* a shortcut for "binding to itself" (in the sense of [RelativeSource.Self](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.self)). Rather, `{Binding}` [is equivalent to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path) `{Binding Path=.}`, which binds to the current source.

---

**To elaborate**: A binding has a *source* and a *path*. You can do a "binding to itself", for example, by using

```
<myUIControl myProperty="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=x}" />
```

This, however, sets the *source* to the control itself, so it will try to access property `x` of the UI control (rather than property `x` of the current data context). From how I understood your question, this is not what you want; in particular, it is not what `{Binding}` does: `{Binding}` keeps the source as it is (usually the `DataContext` of some parent element) and binds to the source itself (equivalent to `Path=.`).

Comment: I have a DataGrid where if the user accesses one of its ContextMenu's MenuItem's Command's via an InputBinding's KeyBinding whose `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}"`, it'll pass the SelectedItems to the Bound ICommand.  However, `null` is passed if it's accessed via the ContextMenu.  I've tried `CommandParameter=` "{Binding SelectedItems}"`, `"{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}"` and `"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItems}"`.

Comment: @Tom: This is hard to answer in a comment. Please create a new question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

another way to bind to self :

```
{Binding {}}
```

an empty `{}` binds to the RelativeSource.Self.