# How do I bind to RelativeSource Self?

Tags: wpf, binding

I am trying to bind several different properties in my Xaml:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Description}" 
Visibility="{Binding Path=DescriptionVisibility, 
ElementName=_UserInputOutput}"               
FontSize="{Binding Path=FontSizeValue, ElementName=_UserInputOutput}"  
HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" />
```

You will noticed I have used two Different binding techniques here.  The ones using Element Name work, the other does not. Here is code behind:

```
public string Description
{
     get { return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); }
     set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("Description", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl), 
new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

Each Binding has a different name but they all look like this for the most part.
I want my Binding to be able to work with:

```
{Binding Description}
```

Instead of:

```
{Binding Path=Description, ElementName=_UserInputOutput}
```

It only seems to be working when ElementName is used.  I need to export/import this XAML, so I can't have a ElementName or the import won't work.

I thought this would be best:

```
{Binding Path=Description, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

This did not work.

Any ideas??  Thank you!

Comment: [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) might be of interest.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You haven't set the DataContext, which is what the RelativeSource is using to determine what it's relative to. You need to set the DataContext at a higher level, like the UserControl. I typically have:

```
<UserControl ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
</UserControl>
```

This tells the UserControl to bind itself the class in the codebehind.

Comment: "which is what the RelativeSource is using to determine what it's relative to" That statement is plain incorrect. Also setting the DataContext of a UserControl is rarely a good idea...

Comment: I think this is not a good idea since it violates the MVVM paradigm: When we want to use WPF with MVVM we have a View that binds to its ViewModel. So inside the constructor of the code behind of the View we say `View() { InitializeComponent(); DataContext = new ViewModel(); }`
This makes all data binding operations work on the ViewModel so we can separate the view from the ViewModel.

Comment: Its unlikely that you want (or even need) to do what is suggested here. The upvotes seem ill-advised.

Comment: @codingdave I agree except there's some thinking that you can simplify using your controls in a hierarchy if you either let the parent set the view model or use binding to bind the dependency.

Answer (score 41):

`{RelativeSource Self}` targets the object that owns the property that is being bound, if you have such a binding on a `Label` it will look for `Label.Description`, which isn't there. Instead you should use `{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}`.

Bindings without a source (`ElementName`, `Source`, `RelativeSource`) are relative to the `DataContext`, however in `UserControls` you should [*avoid* setting the `DataContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572005/setting-datacontext-within-usercontrol-is-affecting-bindings-in-parent) to not mess with external bindings.